# C++ Pointer to unordered_map entry changes, but entry not

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

I'm trying to set a variable of unordered_map entry "chunk" by calling a function using a pointer to this entry. The pointer changes its value "chunkIndex", but the map entry not

```
glm::ivec3 chunkIndex(1, 1, 1);
chunks.insert(make_pair(chunkIndex, Chunk()));
chunk = &chunks[chunkIndex];
chunk->setChunkIndex(chunkIndex);

logVector(chunk->chunkIndex);                      // output: 1, 1, 1
logVector(chunks[chunk->chunkIndex].chunkIndex);   // output: 0, 0, 0
```

"chunks" is an unordered_map of type:

```
typedef unordered_map<glm::ivec3, Chunk, KeyHash, KeyEqual> ChunkMap;
```

Do you know why only the pointer changes its value, and not the referenced object?

Thanks in advance!

**Update:**

```
chunks.insert(make_pair(chunkIndex, Chunk()));
log((chunks.find(chunkIndex) == chunks.end()) ? "true" : "false");
```

This code outputs true, so it the inserted entry actually doesn't exist!

This might be useful too:

```
struct KeyHash
{
    size_t operator()(const glm::ivec3& k)const
    {
        return std::hash<int>()(k.x) ^ std::hash<int>()(k.y) ^ std::hash<int>()(k.z);
    }
};
struct KeyEqual
{
    bool operator()(const glm::ivec3& a, const glm::ivec3& b)const
    {
        return a.x < b.x || (a.x == b.x && a.y < b.y) || (a.x == b.x && a.y == b.y && a.z < b.z);
    }
};

typedef unordered_map<glm::ivec3, Chunk, KeyHash, KeyEqual> ChunkMap;
```

Iterating through the keys also outputs 1, 1, 1

```
for (auto it : chunks) {
    logVector(it.first);
}
```

Comment: It sounds like there are two different chunk indices here: the chunk index used as a key, and the chunk index stored inside the `Chunk` object.

Comment: Right, but both indizes have the same value so they're the same keys!?

Comment: your equality funcion object doesn't seem to be consistent…

Comment: Initially they have the same value, but then you change the chunk index stored inside the `Chunk` object, so they end up with different values. If the chunk index is something that can be changed, using it as the key might not be a good idea.

Comment: The chunk index is always the same for every chunk, so I can access them by position

Comment: And how could I change the chunkIndex of the chunk my pointer is pointing at? (execute a function in context of the object my pointer is pointing at)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `KeyEqual` doesn't implement equality. Replace it with:

```
return a.x == b.x && a.y == b.y && a.z == b.z;
```